# ONLY on IE, form DOM id returns "is null or not an object" problem

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

You can see my code in action here: http://www.illyabbi.com/questions/test5.html

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="scripts/OptionTransfer.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var opt = new OptionTransfer("list1","list2");
opt.setAutoSort(false);
opt.setDelimiter(",");
opt.setStaticOptionRegex("^()$");
opt.saveRemovedLeftOptions("removedLeft");
opt.saveRemovedRightOptions("removedRight");
opt.saveAddedLeftOptions("addedLeft");
opt.saveAddedRightOptions("addedRight");
opt.saveNewLeftOptions("newLeft");
opt.saveNewRightOptions("newRight");
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="opt.init(document.forms[0])">
       
<FORM name="challengeitems">    

<a href="#" class="piece03" onmouseover="document.challengeitems.mySelect.options.piece01.selected=true" onmouseout="document.challengeitems.list1.options.piece01.selected=false" onclick="opt.transferRight()">PIECE01</a>

<a href="#" class="piece03" onmouseover="document.challengeitems.mySelect.options[1].selected=true" onmouseout="document.challengeitems.list1.options[1].selected=false" onclick="opt.transferRight()">PIECE02</a>

<a href="#" class="piece03" onmouseover='document.challengeitems.mySelect.options.piece03.selected=true' onmouseout='document.challengeitems.list1.options.piece03.selected=false' onclick="opt.transferRight()">PIECE01</a>

<a href="#" class="piece03" onmouseover="document.challengeitems.mySelect.options[3].selected=true" onmouseout="document.challengeitems.list1.options[3].selected=false" onclick="opt.transferRight()">PIECE02</a>

    <SELECT id="mySelect" NAME="list1" MULTIPLE SIZE=10 onDblClick="opt.transferRight()">
        <OPTION id="piece01" VALUE="PIECE01">PIECE01</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece02" VALUE="PIECE02">PIECE02</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece03" VALUE="PIECE03">PIECE03</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece04" VALUE="PIECE04">PIECE04</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece05" VALUE="PIECE05">PIECE05</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece06" VALUE="PIECE06">PIECE06</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece07" VALUE="PIECE07">PIECE07</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece08" VALUE="PIECE08">PIECE08</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece09" VALUE="PIECE09">PIECE09</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece10" VALUE="PIECE10">PIECE10</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece11" VALUE="PIECE11">PIECE11</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="piece12" VALUE="PIECE12">PIECE12</OPTION>
        <OPTION id="a" VALUE="a"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    
<!-- RECEIVING BOX -->
    <SELECT NAME="list2" MULTIPLE SIZE=10 onDblClick="opt.transferLeft()">
        <OPTION id="a" VALUE="a"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     </SELECT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm trying to select specific items in a multiple via mouseover and have

```
onmouseover='document.challengeitems.mySelect.options.piece03.selected=true'
```

as opposed to

```
onmouseover="document.challengeitems.mySelect.options[1].selected=true"
```

while the options[1] (or options[x] if in a variable) works all across, you can see the problem of being able to click it again and again (mouse out then in and click).

I only want each select to be clicked one time.

Answer (score 2):

You have an ID, so go directly to it.

```
document.getElementById('piece03').setAttribute("selected","true")
```

Comment: i just started on stackoverflow.com and am already LOVING IT!

Comment: It's the place to be. :) Better than anything out there, I think. Reputational currency at work.

Comment: i just need to learn how to navigate it a little better. lost my other comments..  i was writing:  I simply plugged in Diodeus' code and voila! no more IE errors.  I had to dumb it down like my previous dom code as his returned multiple selects, but probably because I didn't plug it in consistently.  In any case, you can see the fixed code here - http://www.illyabbi.com/questions/20110908_ieBug_fixed.html.  Also, I had not seen them until later, but I also want to thank the others for their answers too!

Comment: doh! but now I see once an item is clicked, as it has disappeared from the first list, it returns the error once more!  darn IE.

Answer (score 0):

The event object in JS contains a link to the element that triggered the event. If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you've got something like:

```
<select multi height="xxx">
   <option value="1" onmouseover="...">1</option>
   <option value="2" onmouseover="...">2</option>
   <option value="3" onmouseover="...">3</option>
</select>
```

You can use `onmouseover="event.target.selected = true;` instead, to save you having to code in which element you're on for each mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

```
onmouseover="for(var i=0; i<document.challengeitems.mySelect.options.length; i++) 
  {if (document.challengeitems.mySelect.options[i].id=='piece01')
      document.challengeitems.mySelect.options[i].selected=true;}"
```

...repeat *ad nauseam*.